# Use mock object in test method implementation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a question. There's a method with implementation using another objects. I'd like to test this method which will not using another objects invoking.

```
class Object1 {

    public void method1() {
        Object2 object2 = new Object2();
        String info = object2.getInfo();
        // ...
        // working with info, which I want to test
        // ...
    }

}

class Object1Test {
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        Object1 object1 = new Object1();
        object1.method(); // want to run this method without invoking Object2
    }
}
```

Could you help me to understand how in junit while testing method1() can I mock the using of Object2 with something like Object2Mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some changes to your class to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
class Object1 {
    private Object2 object2 = new Object2();

    /* Setter Method for Object2 */
    public void setObject2(Object2 object2) {
         this.object2 = object2;
    }

    public void method1() {
        String info = object2.getInfo();
        // ...
        // working with info, which I want to test
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now you just have to call your setter-method with the mocked object for Object2.

```
class Object1Test {
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        Object1 object1 = new Object1();
        object1.setObject2(/* Pass your mocked object here */);
        object1.method(); // want to run this method without invoking Object2
    }
}
```

You can also use `Mockito` or `JMock` to create the object mocks. You can simply tell Mockito to return the dummy response whenever `getInfo()` is invoked on `Object2`. For example,

```
Mockito.when(mockedObject2.getInfo()).thenReturn("Dummy Response");
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are creating a new object within your method. You can refactor your code like this:

```
class Object1 {

    public void method1() {
        Object2 object2 = getObject2();
        String info = object2.getInfo();
        // ...
        // working with info, which I want to test
        // ...
    }
    public Object2 getObject2() {
     return new Object2();
    }
```

With the above code, now you can mock the method `getObject2()` while testing `method1()`.

Comment: You're wrong. You shouldn't mock the same class your trying to test. The creation of Object2 should be outside of Object1

Comment: We can simply use a setter method for `Object2` in `Object1` class to set the mocked object from the test class.

Comment: @jfcorugedo, we should not mock the *method* which is being unit tested. IMHO, its perfectly valid to mock other methods of the *same* class. They will get covered in their own unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your code is not prepare for pure unit testing.

The reason is that Object1 is creating an instance of Object2. There is no way to easily mock a new statement.

I recommend you to use another approach (dependency injection, receive the object as a parameter or in the constructor).

If you can't change the relation between Object1 and Object2, you can use PowerMock.

Take a look at: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor

But take into account that PowerMock should be used only when there is no alternatives. The use of PowerMock denotes a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection should be applied:

```
public class Object1 {
    Object2 object2;

    public Object1(Object2 object2) {
        this.object2 = object2;
    }

    public void method1() {
        String info = object2.getInfo();
    }

}
```

and in test:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.*;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.junit.*;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Object1Test {
    Object1 object1;
    @Mock
    Object2 mockedObject2;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        object1 = new Object1(mockedObject2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        Mockito.when(mockedObject2.getInfo()).thenReturn("Mocked response");

        object1.method1();
    }
}
```

In code which you provided only PowerMockito is solution but it's strongly not recommended.